# Utilizing MySQL multi-column indexes with my JOIN statement

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble utilizing my MySQL multi-column indexes when joining. Maybe a bit of a newbie question, but I appreciate the help.

I have a multi-column index on the notification table across the "type", "status" and "timeSent" columns.

Running this query:

```
SELECT count(notificationID) FROM notification
WHERE statusID = 2
AND typeID = 1
AND timeSent BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND "2014-02-01"
```

This uses my 3 column index and runs fast. If I want to get notifications for a specific client I need to join in my user table.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.notificationID) FROM notification a
  LEFT JOIN user b ON a.userID = b.userID
 WHERE a.statusID = 2
   AND a.typeID = 1
   AND b.clientID = 1
   AND a.timeSent BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND "2014-02-01"
```

This query ignores my index all together and screeches to halt as there are 15m records in the notification table. I've tried doing a sub-select instead with the same results.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notification table is pretty big, so it's not cheap to goof around trying to add indexes. But I will suggest that anyhow.

First of all, `COUNT(*)` is well known to be faster than `COUNT(someColumn)`. I think you can make that change without changing the meaning of your query.

Second, your `(typeID, statusID, timeSent)` covering index is perfect for your first query. MySQL can random-access the index to the first date, sequentially scan to the second date, and just count the index entries, and so satisfy your query.

Third, let's take a look at that clientId-finding query.  What it actually does is look up a date-range of notifications for particular, single, values of `statusID`, `typeID`, and `userID`.  You specify the first two of those explicitly, and the query pulls the third one from the joined table. So, another covering index on `(userID, typeID, statusID, timeSent)` might very well do the trick for you.

Comment: I'm adding the index now, gonna take a bit, but these queries are run on a read replica so not too worried about over indexing affecting the update/insert times.

Comment: Added the index and it appears to be using my new index and load time is back down to a manageable duration. Thanks for the help!